# best layout for my android application

Tags: android, android-layout

I am building a twitter client android application.Say i am now on "timeline" page of my app.

A typical timeline page shows the recent tweets with additional info like location of the tweet,application name etc.

So my question is how to design a layout for such an application.provide me some samples.
thanks

Comment: Design your layout with a pencil and some paper to begin with.

Comment: I had my concept of what to show on the screen.My doubt is how to implement.Should I need to design list views for each individual tweet? or is there any best way

Comment: I think posting a small sketch how you worked that out would help a lot here. Otherwise people guess around and chances are that no one has the right idea in the end.

Comment: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_GTM_W5mVPTU/S-rpD1sUVLI/AAAAAAAAAEU/Wiij849F5S4/s400/tweets2.png this one is similar

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you know about basic android widgets etc in the answer, if not, just ask...

My suggestion would be to follow the conventions set out by the android team, for example have an action bar at the top, with buttons such as to create a new tweet/search tweets and then have a list view below it. If you choose to use a list view, then the list row and list adapter will be the things to customise for showing photos, and other info about tweets.

Or, you could use a view flipper (or similar, but slightly more challenging to implement technique) to slide between tweets, where a single tweet takes up the whole screen at any one time.

I hope that's helpful.